# Looking for a photo management solution

Tags: plugins, images, file-manager

I need a good solution to manage a lot of photos (several thousand+). My ideal scenario is to rip my camera card onto an FTP, then, a single gallery is created from that card rip. Someone can go in to the backend to delete rejects and queue up some photos that need post processing. I'd also like to tag and categorize them for easy search-ability.

I kinda thought about it and wordpress has this functionality built in if I upload the pictures as posts. It's hard to manage them because you can't see the thumbnail in the default post view.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is quite limited when it comes to managing media, it has no real media API, your best to look for a solution that specializes in photos, like  Picasa, Smugmug, iPhoto, jalbum,  etc. You can also integrate these services into WordPress since some of them have an API.

If you need more features you should google "open source DAM" (digital asset management), or use an enterprise solution.